# How to do selection sort?

Tags: c++, sorting

> Count all the records from the file "8.dat". To read each individual recording perform dynamic memory capture.
>
> Sort the records to different keys:
>
> - Item number (ascending);
> - The cost (descending);
> - Number of stock (descending).
>
> Use selection sort
>
> Total sorting will be done 12 times, each time the array is sorted in its original condition.
> For each case count of comparisons to and permutations.

Below code implements insertion sort. Twice, without saying so much.
I need to use selection sort. How to do selection sort?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
 
using namespace std;
 
struct PRICE  
{
    int number;
    char name[20];
    int cost;
    int quantity;
} *pm;
 
int Menu();
void PrintPRICE(PRICE);
void sort_cost(PRICE*, int);
void sort_quantity(PRICE*, int);
 
long file_size(const char*);
 
int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    const char *fname = "D:\8.dat";
 
    FILE* file = fopen(fname, "r");
    if (file != NULL)
    {
        long size = file_size(fname);
        count = size / sizeof PRICE;
        pm = new PRICE[count];
        fread(pm, sizeof PRICE, count, file);
        fclose(file);
    }
 
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        PrintPRICE(pm[i]);
        cout << endl;
    }
 
    int ch = Menu();
 
    switch (ch)
    {
    case 1:
        {
            sort_cost(pm, count);
            cout << endl;
            cout << " Result: " << endl;
            cout << "-----------------------" << endl;
            for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
            {
                PrintPRICE(pm[i]);
                cout << endl;
            }
            break;
        }
    case 2:
        {
            sort_quantity(pm, count);
            cout << " Result: " << endl;
            cout << "-----------------------" << endl;
            for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
            {
                PrintPRICE(pm[i]);
                cout << endl;
            }
            break;
        }
    default: break;
    }
 
    delete [] pm;
    _getch();
}
 
void PrintPRICE(PRICE price)
{
    cout << " Product: " << price.name << endl;
    cout << " Number of orden: " << price.number << endl;
    cout << " Product cost: " << price.cost << endl;
    cout << " Quantity in stock: " << price.quantity << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------------n" << endl;
}
 
long file_size(const char* filename)
{
    FILE *Pfile = NULL;
    Pfile = fopen(filename, "rb");
    fseek(Pfile, 0, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(Pfile);
    fclose(Pfile);
    return size;
}
 
void sort_cost(PRICE* array, int count)
{
    int change = 0;
    int comparesion = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<count; i++)
    {
        PRICE key = array[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        comparesion++;
 
        while (i>=0 && array[i].cost>key.cost)
        {
            array[j + 1] = array[j];
            j = j - 1;
            change++;
        }
        array[j + 1] = key;
    }
    cout << "n Quantity change: " << change << endl;
    cout << " Quantity comparesion: " << comparesion << endl;
}
 
void sort_quantity(PRICE* array, int count)
{
    int change = 0;
    int comparesion = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<count; i++)
    {
        PRICE key = array[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        comparesion++;
        while (j>=0 && array[i].quantity>key.quantity)
        {
            array[j + 1] = array[j];
            j = j - 1;
            change++;
        }
        array[j + 1] = array[j];
    }
    cout << "n Quantity change: " << change << endl;
    cout << " Quantity comparesion: " << comparesion << endl;
}
 
int Menu()
{
    int n;
    cout << " 1 - Sort by cost" << endl;
    cout << " 2 - Sort by quantity" << endl;
    cout << "n Your choice: "; cin >> n;
    return n;
}
```

Comment: `This code is used insertion sort. I need to use selection sort. How can I do?` --> Use selection sort instead of insertion sort.

Answer (score 0):

source code for the selection sort

```
void selectSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    int pos_min,temp;

    for (int i=0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        pos_min = i;        
        for (int j=i+1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] < arr[pos_min])
                pos_min=j;
        }
        
        if (pos_min != i)
        {
             temp = arr[i];
             arr[i] = arr[pos_min];
             arr[pos_min] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to sort the records of the structure.